# Expandable List View doesn't expand

Tags: java, android, layout

Here is my custom expandable adapter and my main activity. The problem is that when I click on an item it doesn't expand!

```
public class LocationListActivity extends /*ExpandableList*/Activity {

    private ExpandableListView elv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location_list_layout);

        final ExpadableAdapter adapter = new ExpadableAdapter();
        elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpandableListView);
        elv.setAdapter(adapter);

        elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {


            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                int len = adapter.getGroupCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (i != groupPosition) {
                        elv.collapseGroup(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                //causes out of bounds exception. has to be done on Collapse for some reason.

                // int len = mAdapter.getGroupCount();
                // for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                // if (i != groupPosition) {
                // parent.collapseGroup(i);
                // }
                // }

                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_location_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class ExpadableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names",
        "Fish Names" };
        private String[][] children = { { "Arnold" }, { "Ace" }, { "Fluffy" },
                { "Goldy" } };

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalater = (LayoutInflater) LocationListActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_parent_row_layout, null);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LocationListActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_parent_row_layout, null);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how I can fix my problem? I saw somewhere on SO that you have to set some of the views to enabled:false, but I don't know which view to set to false, and the answer wasn't explained thoroughly. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you want to have a different layout for group and child. Now your convertView is the same in getChildView() as well as in getGroupView(), I mean you are inflating R.layout.expandable_list_parent_row_layout two times. But maybe that's not the problem. I think there might be problem with elv.collapseGroup(i);. Put Log inside of onGroupExpand() method and see what happens.

Comment: i switched the layouts still nothing